# Android dependencies libraries must be exact same version

Tags: android, firebase, dependencies, build.gradle

This is the error message I am getting from this line: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'` in the dependencies in my apps `build.gradle`:

```
All com.google.android.gms libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 15.0.4, 15.0.1, 15.0.0. Examples include com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:15.0.4 and com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:15.0.1
```

Anyone know how to get rid of this error message?

This is my app gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my build gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.company.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 14
        versionName "1.4"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0' //Error line
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[image]

Comment: try with version 15.0.1 :)

Comment: @BorislavKamenov No, because some of those dependencies don't even have a version 15.0.1.

Comment: Please add the entire content of your both build.gradle files and please responde with @.

Comment: I updated the question with both build gradle files @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much exactly as it says. Your com.google.android.gms:play-service* dependencies should all be the same version.

If we could see the code/your gradle file, then that may help.~

It states you have 3 dependency versions...15.0.0,15.0.1 and 15.0.4.
They should all be the same (15.0.04 for example).

Looking at the maven repos, the most up to date for all that are a common version is 15.0.0.

Comment: I updated the question with the dependencies! Check it out.

Comment: I updated the question, please have a look at it! @Jcov

Answer (score 0):

You need to update google-service plugin to use:

> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
>   to be able to avoid those errors, also upgrade to android studio 3.1

If you're not using Android Studio 3.1 to develop your app, you will need to upgrade in order to get the correct version checking behavior within the IDE.